# Specify a filename suffix with easy-thumbnails in django

Tags: django, easy-thumbnails

I am using the easy-thumbnails lib in django to create thumbnails. However, I can't figure out how to override the thumbnail naming process. At the moment the lib is appending the thumbnail size to the file name, but I would like to specify a custom name e.g. _large. How can this be done please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django-easy-thumbnails` uses [default renaming function](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails/blob/master/easy_thumbnails/namers.py#L7). You can write your own naming function and set it in settings as a default naming function the library should use, as described here [THUMBNAIL_NAMER](http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/settings/#easy_thumbnails.conf.Settings.THUMBNAIL_NAMER):

**myapp.utils**

```
def namer(thumbnailer, prepared_options, source_filename,
          thumbnail_extension, **kwargs):
   # do something and return name
   pass
```

**settings.py**

```
THUMBNAIL_NAMER = 'myapp.utils.namer'
```

Comment: I've added an issue around using the alias in the thumbnail filename generation: https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails/issues/375

Answer (score 0):

you can define your own `thumbnail-processor` and put as last line here: http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/settings/#easy_thumbnails.conf.Settings.THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS

```
THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS = (
   'easy_thumbnails.processors.colorspace',
   'easy_thumbnails.processors.autocrop',
   'easy_thumbnails.processors.scale_and_crop',
   'easy_thumbnails.processors.filters',
   'easy_thumbnails.processors.background',
   'yourProject.thumbnail_processors.renaming', #<---- your custom one 
)
```

and your processor file (`yourProject/thumbnail_processors.py`) would look like:

```
def renaming(image, bang=False, **kwargs):
    """
    rename the filename here and just return the image
    """
    return image
```

not tested though

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i'm not quite sure how to "rename the filename". The image is a  PIL object and has no property named filename.